# Multiple Checkpoints / Respawning Zones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

Basically I have three classes to try and collect the checkpoints and respawn at the last one reached. The code seems fine, however I'm getting a null reference error upon reaching the checkpoint during runtime. The problem seems to be inside Unity.

```
private CheckPoint cp;
```

I can't get anything to go into the inspector section for this instance. Granted, I do a call upon start

```
 cp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Checkpoint").GetComponent<CheckPoint>();
```

I've tired an empty object and I've tried placing one of my checkpoint objects but nothing seems to work. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a GameObject in the scene with the Checkpoint tag? If so, take screenshot of it Inspector tab and post it

Comment: I snapped photos of both my checkpoints and posted one for you to view. Couldn't post more than 1 image. StackedOverflow doesn't permit such useful functions lol :p

Comment: The `CheckPoint`  script is attached to the Respawn01 Object and you can see the Respawn01 Object in the Hierarchy tab? id you call the `Destroy` function anywhere in your code? Did you deactivate the GameObject anywhere in your code with the `SetActive` function?

Comment: private static CheckPoint spawn;
     public Vector2 lastCheck;
     void Awake()
    {
        if (spawn == null)
        {

            spawn = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(spawn);

        }
        else
        {

            Destroy(gameObject);

Comment: Yes, Respawn01 has always had the script on it because it wasn't originally going to be a checkpoint system, only a respawn. However, testing my game is getting to the point where I'd rather have a checkpoint system. Should I not have the script attached?

Comment: Is the game lineal? I mean, if you have 4 checkpoints in the following order A,B,C and D. And for any reason, the player skips checkpoint B, and pass through A, C and then goes back to B. Where should the player respawn in C or in B? I have an approach in mind, but I prefer you clarify first about this matter.

Comment: Basically I have two spawn zones in level 1. The very beginning is default and right before entering the boss zone. That way the player must make it through the level, but can keep attempting the boss without having to run through the level again. The game is a side scroller platform style. Think of it like an old megaman/ super mario on nintendo. Maybe a hint of Metroid. Old school baby! lol  However, I have the checkpoints setup where there is no avoiding them.

Comment: Basically I have an Empty game object named CheckPoint and then an empty named RespewnPoints(Was the original parent before multiple checkpoints set up) then two children Respawn01 and CheckPoint_Boss_LvL01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Check if you have multiple gameObjects tagged "CheckPoint".

```
cp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Checkpoint").GetComponent<CheckPoint>();
```

is going to find the first gameObject with that tag and try to get your component, if there is no component, you will get null reference

**2.** Use this instead

```
FindObjectsOfType<Checkpoint>();
```

for more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

**3.** Use a list/array/any other container in your "CheckpointManager" class and into Start() method of each Checkpoint do:

```
CheckpointManager.container.add(this);
```

this should be much easier to manage and you will not have to use tags.